# How to cast video to Sony TV

Tags: android, google-cast, sony

I was using the [CastCompanionLibrary](https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android) to build an application. In my network, I had a Chromecast device and a Sony Bravia TV. When I clicked on  my app's`MediaRouteButton`, I only saw the ChromeCast:

[image: My app]

But when I used the YouTube application, I saw:

[image: Youtube]

**How can I discover my TV and cast my video to it like YouTube did?**

Comment: you probably need to write a BRAVIA app for the tv..
related:
 http://forums.androidcentral.com/google-chromecast/300359-want-try-casting-without-chromecast-some-cases-you-can.html  and  http://www.chromestory.com/2015/01/sonys-latest-bravia-4k-tv-chromecast-support-built/ and https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/1krkaz/found_out_today_that_many_tvs_have_chromecast/

Comment: @Henrik thank for your quickly response, i'm watching on it.